# Android strings.xml not in R.id

Tags: android, string

I am unable to see my values in my strings.xml
When I try to see it in R.id it doesnt exist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">BPhonelist</string>
    <string name="action_add_contact">Add Contact</string>
    <string name="action_phone_contact">Phone Contact</string>
    <string name="action_work_contact">Phone Work Contact</string>
    <string name="action_home_contact">Phone Home Contact</string>
    <string name="action_email_contact">Email Contact</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="detail_toast_add">Contact Added</string>

</resources>
```

Please if you know how I can get access it tell me.

Comment: String resources would be in R.string, not R.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to see it in R.id it doesnt exist

that's because these are in your `strings.xml`. They aren't `id resources`. Try accessing with something like

```
String someString = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
```

This is assuming you are already in the `Activity Context`. If not, you will need to have a `Context` before `getResources()`

Answer (score 1):

`R.id.*` values will be generated from layout files using `android:id="+@id\myid"`

You can reference your strings via the `R.string.` prefix.